# Check if object has given properties

Tags: php, oop

Other than doing something like the below code, is there a better way to check if an object has several given properties?

```
<?php
class myClass
{
    public $a=1;
    public $b=2;
    public $c=3;

    public function checkProperties($obj,$props)
    {
        $status=true;
        foreach($props as $prop) {
            if(!isset($obj->$prop)){$status=false;break;}
        }
        return $status;
    }
}
$myObj=new myClass();
print_r($myObj);
echo($myObj->checkProperties($myObj,array('a','b','c'))?'true':'false');
echo($myObj->checkProperties($myObj,array('a','d','c'))?'true':'false');
?>
```

Comment: Please use getters and setters - better pattern than `public $a=1`

Comment: A better way, perhaps like (for example) using the magic [__isset() method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.isset)?

Comment: You can use this `property_exists ($class , $property)` to check if a property exists inside a class. It requires PHP >= 5.3.

Comment: @MarkBaker  How could this be done?

Comment: You can pass both class name and object to  `property_exists`.  It will return true or false based on the status of your class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use at least three ways to do it:

- [`property_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php)
- [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.isset.php)
- [`ReflectionClass::hasProperty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.hasproperty.php)

All of these are demonstrated below:

```
<?php
class myClass
{
    public $a=1;
    public $b=2;
    public $c=3;
}

$myObj = new myClass();
$reflectionClass = new ReflectionClass($myObj);
foreach (['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] as $property)
{
    printf("Checking if %s exists: %d %d %d\n",
        $property,
        property_exists($myObj, $property),
        isset($myObj->$property),
        $reflectionClass->hasProperty($property));
}
```

Output:

```
Checking if a exists: 1 1 1
Checking if b exists: 1 1 1
Checking if c exists: 1 1 1
Checking if d exists: 0 0 0
```

Each column is a result of applying corresponding technique from the top of my post.

Comment: Thanks rr.  Was thinking there might be something like `array_diff_assoc()` which would do it...